# Is there a way to embed / display AWS user interface within your application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, user-interface, embed

We have been using AWS QuickSight dashboards within our application, but now want to look into doing the same with the AWS Pinpoint user interfaces.

Has someone done or found a way to enable AWS authentication and URL of an application to be shown from within their application. I am trying to do it with API Gateway and using Lambda functions, but not sure on how to use that URL within my application.

My URL is this one:

https://ap-southeast-2.console.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/home?region=ap-southeast-2#/apps/5dc9389deb974230bb8ce53e53f098a6/journeys/37904541e6d24bd9aea268e15c6bd043/edit

I want to display it from within my application. Would it be possble to add a authentication to this and use it, or is there some other way?

Comment: You mean something like [AWS Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/)?

Comment: @Mornor - Can I use AWS Cognito to authenticate and get the application UI to show up as an embedded one in my own application window? If so, have you tried it?

Comment: Yes you can, see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-integration.html). Never did it myself.